# Excel VBA - The microsoft Office Access data engine could not find the object

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have issues with a VBA project in Excel that used to work before for over a year.

My code is below, the last line is what gives the error. What I am trying to do is querying a sheet on the same workbook. I have other queries that call other workbooks but this module that calls a sheet on the same workbook is whats giving troubles.

Some key information:

- The workbook is binary
- The `srcDataSheet` value is *[Data$A1:Y68277]*. Of course, the row number could change but columns will always be A to Y.
- Sheet named *Data* does exist.
- Tried changing providers. `strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _ & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"`

What could possibly be causing this error when the workbook worked perfectly for over a year? Please help.

```
Sub QueryDataSheet(srcDataSheet As String)

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strFile As String, strCon As String, strSQL As String, strRangeAddress As String
Dim iCols As Long, lastRow As Long, fLastRow As Long

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT [PLANT], [FILTER_PLANT], [Rule], [SKU], [Style], [Color], [Size Code], " & _
         "Sum(IIf([Order_Type2]='XDR', [Corrected Qty], 0)) AS XDR, Sum(IIf([Order_Type2]='XDR CONSUMED', [Corrected Qty], 0)) AS XDR_CONSUMED, " & _
         "Sum(IIf([Order_Type2]='EXCESS', [Corrected Qty], 0)) AS EXCESS, [RULE_RANGE], [I Indicator] " & _
         "FROM " & srcDataSheet & " " & _
         "WHERE [PLANT] IN ('0F','4J') " & _
         "GROUP BY [PLANT], [FILTER_PLANT], [Rule], [SKU], [Style], [Color], [Size Code], [RULE_RANGE], [I Indicator]"


rs.Open strSQL, cn 'ERROR HERE
```

Comment: Why would row number change? Why ms-access tag? Why use Excel as a database? ACE works for me. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: `[Data$A1:Y68277]` did you mean  `[Data!$A1:Y68277]` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, works fine without ! character. The variable is declared as an argument in procedure declaration.

Comment: @June7, Because the data the user pastes could be more or less in rows. Ms-access tag because the error says Access data base engine and it was recommended as a tag. Because users didnt want to 'lose time' in opening both access and Excel and I simply lacked the will to change their views and I already had the code mostly done from past projects. ACE?

Comment: ACE from the alternate provider you attempted: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB`.

Comment: Yes - I missed the parameter...

Comment: Since neither Access database nor Access VBA are actually involved, don't see relevance of ms-access tag. But an SQL statement is involved so added that tag.

Comment: Did it work when you had fewer rows? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543744/oledb-connection-to-support-more-than-65536-rows-update-access-from-excel-sheet

Comment: Ah, I neglected to use row numbers in my code. Now I do get that error. Reduced to 65000 and code runs.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert - I deleted some rows and it worked. I changed to using "[Data$A:Y]" and this helped.

Comment: @June7,  what did you do when you had to work with more than 65K rows?

Comment: I've never had to. I don't use Excel as a database.